# I can't seem to reset the position of the control bone

Tags: rigging, constraints

I have made a foot control rig here, but I try alt-G, and alt-R and it does not reset the pose. I even tried resetting it from the pose menu up there in the top left. Any ideas? I'm just sure it has to do with the bone constraints, but I can't figure it out on my own! Thank you all in advance! You all are the best! Here's a picture if that helps lol.
[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Okay, I'm working on uploading it. Computer just being slow.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=R7vjlOeQ" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/R7vjlOeQ/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a conflict: the controller controls the foot through several bones parentage, the foot controls the leg through the leg's *IK*, and the leg controls the controllers through a *Limit Distance*, so you need to delete the *Limit Distance*. If it was meant to attach the controller to the leg it is not the right way, I don't know any way to do it but there might be a way though... I personally prefer easier bone setup but I'm not a pro.

Comment: Okay, well thanks for looking at it anyhow. The tutorial I'm following is a older one I suppose. I will try to find a way to get it to stick to the mesh. Thank you moonboots!